# Including jQuery UI Sortable in WordPress admin page

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

I'm working on a plugin and encountered a problem where trying to make use of the jQuery UI Sortable. I followed the instruction as in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_Scripts_Only_on_a_Plugin_Administration_Screen) but issue remained. The jQuery UI sortable does not function and Firebug says `TypeError: jQuery(...).sortable is not a function`.

I'm running on WordPress 3.6 and the code is:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Name
Description: Description
Version: 0.1
Author: Bloorchi
*/

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_admin_menu' );

function my_plugin_admin_menu() {
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page_hook_suffix, 'my_plugin_admin_scripts');
    $page_hook_suffix = add_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my_plugin-options', 'my_plugin_manage_menu' );
}

function my_plugin_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' );
}

function my_plugin_manage_menu() {
?>
<table id="test">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>  
    <tbody>    
</table>
<script>
    jQuery('table#test tbody').sortable();
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things, you have this inverted:

```
$suffix = add_submenu_page( 
    'edit.php', 
    'My Plugin', 
    'My Plugin', 
    'manage_options', 
    'my_plugin-options', 
    'my_plugin_manage_menu' 
);
add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$suffix", 'my_plugin_admin_scripts');
```

And you need to always run jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('table#test tbody').sortable();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tested your exact code with this mods and works ok: http://pastebin.com/mXFSR9Bn

Comment: personally, i do it this way to avoid an extra couple keystrokes:
    var $ = jQuery;

Answer (score 1):

her is a simple tut for creating sortable table on wordpress.

http://kvcodes.com/2013/12/create-sortable-tables-in-wordpress-front-end/

and for back end, try this one.

http://kvcodes.com/2014/02/sortable-data-table-wordpress-frontback-end/

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all of your plugins and try it again. I had a similar problem and I found that the problem was in one of the plugins